# Jhipster - [src]="getImageUrl()" for user's avatar image not working

Tags: jhipster

I have updated column: image_url in [jhi_user] table with different values, and nothing seems to work, `example: image_url= ../../../content/media/angular-js.png`

Question:
Where in jhipster's file structure should i create a folder to hold user's profiles pictures, and what should the image_url value be so that it works with
`<img [src]="getImageUrl()">`

It's worth mentioning that this works:
`<img src="../../../content/media/angular-js.png">` 
i created a folder "media" with image: angular-js.png

I am using mysql database and generator-jhipster: "4.6.2"

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kind of images in web apps: the static assets are used for layout (icons, background, logos, ...) they are bundled within your app and the other ones that can be changed without rebuilding your app and which are data.

Static assets can be long term cached by the browser, this is why JHipster uses [webpack to version their URLs](https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95) with a hash code, to modify files that reference them (html, css) and bundle them.

In your design, your image URL is stored in a column of the User entity that points to an avatar image which is a static asset. So webpack is not able to rewrite it.

So either you exclude these images from webpack build process or you store your images as Blobs in your database to enable your users to upload their own images.

Second option would consist in creating a new entity Avatar that holds the Blob and have a one-to-one relationship with User entity. The reason for another entity si that JHipster does not let you modify the User entity.

Comment: I am trying to avoid saving user's images as Blobs in the DB, i just want to store their URL. As i try different options, i created a new folder "media": `content/media/user_image.png` to store user images as data. I stored the url in the DB as `../../../content/media/user_image.png` and trying to load the image using `<img [src]="getImageUrl()">` `getImageUrl()` returns the image URL stored in the BD. This doesn't work, why? am i using the wrong URL format???

Comment: What is that you did not understand in my explanation about URL being rewritten by webpack? Did you read the article in link?

Comment: I put the `media/user_image.png` in `target/www`, using
        `new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './media', to: 'media' }
        ])`, in webpack.dev, so now using the `<img [src]="media/user_image.png"` works fine. This is just for testing, in production i would probably use a Content Delivery Network, like Amazon CloudFront, and just use http urls for images, so this won't be necessary in production situations. I am new to webpack and angular, so i am still learning. Thank you for your help :)